# React Native - How to connect existing account login with facebook/twitter?

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, integrate

I'm new in Javascript and react native, I want to know if there's a way to integrating existing account login with facebook?

so a user can login with his/her facebook or with a username that already registered

I've spent a couple hours to find any tutorial about my issue, but no luck till now

Answer (score 1):

For facebook , you may consider using [`react-native-fbsdk`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login).

As per their docs, they provide, `LoginButton` with various [`permission levels`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

The sample code to to get the login status is as follows

```
     LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(
  function(result) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Login was cancelled');
    } else {
      alert('Login was successful with permissions: '
        + result.grantedPermissions.toString());
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    alert('Login failed with error: ' + error);
  }
);
```

For other `social-auth` support checkout this library [`react-native simple-auth`](https://github.com/adamjmcgrath/react-native-simple-auth), the documentation is well mentioned along with the steps to integrate it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the suggest, but i don't have any logic to integrating the facebook/twitter login with existing account for now, so i need more complex answer, if possible any tutorial on the web would be great, anyway thanks for the answer +1